Substract values dictionary from another dictionary's values
I have a coffee machine that gives a user 3 options to choose from: espresso, latte, cappuccino. The ingredients and cost of the chosen item are stored in a dictionary in the variable MENU. After the user has chosen his coffee I need to be able to print a report which tells me how much resources are left in the machine, the resources being water, milk, coffee. How can I subtract the ingredients (ingredients chosen coffee) from the resources variable and get the remaining resources printed in a report?
MENU = {
    "espresso": {
        "ingredients": {
            "water": 50,
            "coffee": 18,
        },
        "cost": 1.5,
    },
    "latte": {
        "ingredients": {
            "water": 200,
            "milk": 150,
            "coffee": 24,
        },
        "cost": 2.5,
    },
    "cappuccino": {
        "ingredients": {
            "water": 250,
            "milk": 100,
            "coffee": 24,
        },
        "cost": 3.0,
    }
}

resources = {
    "water": 300,
    "milk": 200,
    "coffee": 100,
}

From previous lessons, I learned that I need to format the data from the dictionary so that it becomes usable in the code. But I'm at a very beginner level and I'm stuck after formatting the data.
def format_data(choice):
    """Format ingredients into printable format: water, milk, coffee, cost"""
    water = MENU[user_choice]['ingredients']["water"]
    milk = MENU[user_choice]['ingredients']["milk"]
    coffee = MENU[user_choice]['ingredients']["coffee"]
    cost = MENU[user_choice]['ingredients']["cost"]

user_choice = input("What would you like? (espresso/latte/cappuccino").lower()


@Vitalizzare I've edited the text, hopefully it's more clear now.

Here's an approach:

ask the user for the drink they want

use the drink they chose and the Python in operator to check if that drink is in the MENU dictionary

if the drink is in the MENU dictionary then use the drink choice as the key to the MENU to lookup the recipe (ingredients and quantity) for
their drink (eg. MENU[choice]['ingredients'])

go through each of the ingredients and quantites in the recipe and subtract that quantity from the same ingredient in the resources dictionary
  MENU = {
      "espresso": {
          "ingredients": {
              "water": 50,
              "coffee": 18,
          },
          "cost": 1.5,
      },
      "latte": {
          "ingredients": {
              "water": 200,
              "milk": 150,
              "coffee": 24,
          },
          "cost": 2.5,
      },
      "cappuccino": {
          "ingredients": {
              "water": 250,
              "milk": 100,
              "coffee": 24,
          },
          "cost": 3.0,
      }
  }

  resources = {
      "water":  3000,
      "milk":   2000,
      "coffee": 1000,
  }

  # go into a 'forever' loop and prompt the user for their drink choice

  while True:
      choice = input("choice: ")

      # if input line has a 'q' in it then quit (break out of loop)
      if 'q' in choice:
          print("all done")
          break

      # if input line is not a known drink then prompt to try again
      if choice not in MENU:
          print("don't have that on the menu try again")
          continue

      # if we get here we know its a known drink so get the recipe
      # for the chosen drink and assign it to the the recipe dictionary
      recipe = MENU[choice]['ingredients']

      # now go through the recipe for the chosen drink and 
      # for each ingredient subtract the quantity of that
      # ingredient used from the resources dictionary

      for ingredient, quantity in recipe.items():
          resources[ingredient] -= quantity

      # report the drink was made
      print ("made you a", choice)

      # report the remaining resources after the drink was made
      print ("remaining resources are:")
      for ingredient, quantity in resources.items():
          print(f"{ingredient:6} {quantity:6}")



choice: latte
made you a latte
remaining resources are:
water    2800
milk     1850
coffee    976

choice: latte
made you a latte
remaining resources are:
water    2600
milk     1700
coffee    952

choice: espresso
made you a espresso
remaining resources are:
water    2550
milk     1700
coffee    934

choice: q
all done

